# Magento 2.4.6 mulitple vhosts on a single server and Varnish in Docker

Tags: magento2.4, varnish, docker

Afternoon

I've got Varnish running on a Plesk based server and all is working well based upon the instructions from here:
https://talk.plesk.com/threads/magento-2-plesk-varnish-setup-in-a-docker.362442/

However, I'm adding a second Magento 2.4.6 install to the server and want to use Varnish with it. I can't seem to find anything recent on it.

Question is does Varnish work with multiple Magento 2.4.6 installs or do I need to do something like this recommendation ?
[Multiple Magento 2 installs on 1 Varnish install](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159396/multiple-magento-2-installs-on-1-varnish-install)

Answer (score 1):

Varnish can handle virtual hosts and respects the `Host` header.

As explained in https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#4-vcl_hash, the Varnish built-in behavior will use both the URL and the `Host` header to compose the cache key.

As long as the 2nd Magento site lives on the same server that is mentioned in the `backend` definition of your VCL file, you should be fine.

Comment: I can confirm that Varnish can handle multiple vhosts just fine. I've been running all my dev and sandbox sites on a single linux box with varnish installed alongside apache for years and have never run into an issue. I haven't had to do anything special with the VCL either.